# How to convert an XML file into a .Net class?

Tags: .net, xml

Can someone please remind me how to create a .Net class from an XML file?

I would prefer the batch commands, or a way to integrate it into the shell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The below batch will create a .Net **Class** from **XML** in the current directory.
So... XML -> XSD -> VB

(Feel free to substitute CS for Language)

Create a **Convert2Class.Bat** in the %UserProfile%\SendTo directory.
Then copy/save the below:

```
@Echo off
Set XsdExePath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\XSD.exe"
Set Language=VB
%~d1
CD %~d1%~p1 
%XsdExePath% "%~n1.xml" /nologo
%XsdExePath% "%~n1.xsd" /nologo /c /language:%Language%
```

Works on my machine - Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the xsd.exe tool to generate a class, otherwise you probably have to implement a custom solution against your XML

[XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx)

[XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)